# Copying structs in C with floats as members

Tags: c

I have three structure types as shown below...

```
typedef struct _ABC_
{
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;
}ABC;

typedef struct _XYZ_1_
{
  int a0;
  ABC abc1; 
}XYZ1;

typedef struct _XYZ_2
{
  int a1;
  ABC abc2;
}XYZ2;
```

I want to copy the struct ABC in the struct XYZ2 to the struct ABC defined as a member in struct XYZ1.

I know the most basic way as:

```
fn(){
  XYZ2 xyz2;
  XYZ1 xyz1;

  /* …code to initialize… */

  xyz1.abc1.a = xyz2.abc2.a;
  xyz1.abc1.b = xyz2.abc2.c;
  xyz1.abc1.c = xyz2.abc2.c;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: Efficient = Portable? Better Readability? Faster Runtime?

Comment: Note that names starting with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for use by 'the implementation'.  You should not create names like that for your own use unless you don't mind a change in the compilation system breaking your code.  (You should mind that; you'd have to fix your code, and it would be no-one's fault but your own.)  The full rules are slightly more nuanced than this, but it is safe if you assume "names starting with an underscore are reserved for 'the implementation' and should not be created by ordinary programmers".

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your own code. If you insist on adding typedefs for structure types, you can use the same identifier for the tag and the typedef, since they're in different name spaces: `typedef struct abc { /* ... */ } abc;`. Or just drop the typedef and refer to the type as `struct abc`.

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way (in the sense of short source code, maintainability, extendability, run-time speed, but not necessarily target code-size) would be:

```
xyz1.abc1 = xyz2.abc2;
```

Read about struct assignment.

Note

```
fn()
```

is not a valid function declaration. Please use correct prototype-syntax, K&R-style is long time outdated; since C99 your compiler has to warn about it; C11 has announced obsolescence (hopefully in C17).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response.

Comment: For some reason, that doesnt work on my c compiler. I am using code composer studio which uses a TMS c compiler.

Comment: @ramsurada: "does not work" is no error description. Please be precise!

Comment: @JeremiahDicharry: I did not add a specific signture, as I assume that is not all of `f()`. However, as that is one of the first things to learn, OP should be able to use the correct one. (but, yes, for the snippet given, that would be correct).

Comment: @Olaf : When I say doesnt work, I meant that the values are not being copied from abc2 to abc1 but if i do it the way i specified in my first post i can see the values being copied from source to destination.

Comment: @ Olaf : Sorry I should have been more specific before.

Comment: @ramsurada: Then your compiler is broken. That is standard C! If it does not work, get a standard-compliant compiler. If by "TMS" you mean the ARM Cortex-M MCUs, you can use the gnu-toolchain (gcc, binutils, gdb) plus OpenOCD.

Comment: @ramsurada: That would mean, that you compiler is not ANSI C compliant. I am pretty sure that struct assignments are valid even in ancient C89.

Comment: @Olaf and Grzegorz Thanks a lot guys. I will look into the compiler.

Comment: @ramsurada: A strong personal recommendation: Use **at least** a proper C99 compiler. That includes very useful things, expecially for embedded progamming, like fixed-size data types `stdint.h` and `_Bool`/`stdbool.h` (true boolean datatype). - Although for your current problem, I agree with Grzegorz, that should also work with C90.

Comment: @ramsurada: http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/p/123871/442984 The compliance-page does not even list that crappy behaviour. Wonder what else they left out undocumented. I'd really think of changing the toolchain.

Comment: Structure assignment was part of the C89/C90 standards.  IIRC, it was not part of the C documented in K&R 1st Edition, though it might have forecast.  Certainly, the AT&T derived C compilers from the mid-80s supported structure assignment, and passing and returning structure values (which the C in K&R1 also did not support).  But you have to be using a compiler based on 30-year old technology to be running into this problem today.  I agree with those who said "time to upgrade".  And give the supplier of the overly archaic compiler a kick in the seat of the pants, too.

Comment: Implicit `int` was removed from the language by C99. Old-style (non-prototype) function declarations and definitions have been obsolescent since ANSI C 1989; I'm not optimistic that they'll ever be removed.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Please leave this little bit of hope to me:-}  As much as I hope they will allow to specify the underlying integer type for `enum`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `memcpy` or `memmove`:

```
memcpy(&xyz1.abc1, &xyz2.abc2, sizeof(ABC));
memmove(&xyz1.abc1, &xyz2.abc2, sizeof(ABC));
```